# plotting with ggplot2. Error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the data using the ggplot2 package, but I am crossing with an error:
the data are set of columns which represents every day values (the values change in altitude)

```
V1 V2.... V500
2E-15.....3E-14
3e-14.....3E-21
1.3E-15....NA
```

I want to plot all the data in two axis with a fill of the values.

Code;

```
a<-data.frame("/../vertical_value.csv",sep=",",header=F)
am<-melt(t(a))
dataset<-expand.grid(X = 1:500, H = seq(1,25,by=1))
dataset$axp<-am$value
g<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x = X, y = H, fill = axp)) + geom_tile()
```

error:

```
Error: Casting formula contains variables not found in molten data: XHaxp
```

Comment: Jaun, would it be at all possible to provide us with your data or dummmy data that is in the same shape? The casting error might reflect NA's in your data. na.omit(dataset) may work. But it's hard to tell without seeing what it should be. Also, could someone codify his post properly?

Comment: Please give a reproducible example. I tried your code with `a <- matrix(rnorm(500*25), nc=500)`, and did not get any errors (I also do not understand why can't you use `am` in the plot directly).

Comment: Don't know exactly what's going on here, but I believe your error might be at the melt(t(a)) stage? It's really hard to go further without a reproducible example.  Here's a similar example that works (sorry about the format): z <- data.frame(V1=1:5,V2=2:6,V3=3:7);
library(reshape);
mm <- melt(t(z));
dataset <- expand.grid(X=1:5,H=1:3);
dataset$axp <- mm$value;
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=X,y=H,fill=axp))+geom_tile()

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this again, I think that you should be able to bypass this just by dropping NA rows after you melt.

```
a<-data.frame("/../vertical_value.csv",sep=",",header=F)
am<-melt(t(a))
am <- na.omit(am) ## ADD THIS LINE
dataset<-expand.grid(X = 1:500, H = seq(1,25,by=1))
dataset$axp<-am$value
g<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x = X, y = H, fill = axp)) + geom_tile()
```